# Why is harmonic oscillator creation operator called "a-dagger", $a^\dagger$?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics

As is well known, Dirac introduced the creation and annihilation operators for the quantum harmonic oscillator ($\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}$ respectively), which are now part of every first course in quantum mechanics due to their far-reaching importance and simplicity.

$$\hat{a}^\dagger=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\left[\hat{x}-\frac{i}{m\omega}\hat{p}\right],\,\,\,\hat{a}=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}}\left[\hat{x}+\frac{i}{m\omega}\hat{p}\right]$$

However, in English we say *"a-dagger"* for the creation operator, and the word "dagger" is certainly more associated with destruction (killing, stabbing, etc.) than it is with *"creation"*. This is almost always an unspoken source of confusion for native English-speaking students of physics.

Given that this was originally done by an Englishman, how come we haven't simply swapped the definitions for $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $\hat{a}$, and then called $\hat{a}^\dagger$ the annihilation operator and $\hat{a}$ the creation operator, a redefinition that would have no effect on the physics but have a substantial effect on a student's ability to remember these operators? Is there a reason why Dirac chose this language-awkward definition?

Comment: The name "dagger" is used for the typographical symbol † because of its appearance.  This goes back way before Dirac.  Here, it denotes the complex-conjugate.

Comment: For a discussion about the origin of the dagger, one can check [Why is a cross † used as footnote marker for people?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268585/30315)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\dagger$ is the transpose conjugate of a linear operator; once $a$ is defined as the annihilation operator (presumably because annihilation starts with the letter *a*), Dirac showed that the corresponding creation operator corresponds to it's transpose conjugate, hence the creation operator is $a^{\dagger} $.

Thus the *a* comes first, and then the $\dagger $.

I wouldn't assume that Dirac is responsible for the $\dagger $ notation for transpose conjugate; it is not the only way it is written in mathematical texts, though it is certainly the favorite among physicists today.